# CSS/HTML: Alpha setting applied to background-color makes it disappear

Tags: html, css, background, transparency

System: Linux Mint
Editor: Atom (by GitHub)
Browser: Google Chrome for Linux (43.0)

Question: For styling the div of class biobox in the CSS section of my code, I'm trying to get a semi-transparent background by using background-color:rgb(0,0,0,0.5). This results in no background at all. If I remove the 0.5 (alpha/transparency.opacity value), i get a opaque black background applied to the div. What could be causing this?

```css
h1 {
  font-famiy: Verdana;
  color: #090956;
}
.biobox {
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #090956;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
body {
  background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-backgound-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <h1>This is Big Header</h1>

<div class="biobox">
  <p>This is a subtitle to the header!</p>
</div>

<p>More bio crap!</p>
```

Comment: Use `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`

Comment: @Akshay you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);` instead of `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that i'd have to put in rgba to add alpha settings!